# Symfony form with prepopulated data

Tags: php, forms, types, symfony

I'm having troubles finding the best approach to implement a Symfony form for the next scenario:

I've a group of entities to store a catalog of checklists (Checklists->Groups->Tasks->CorrectiveActions), those checklists can be implemented by the entity Stations.

In this implementation the station will give a score to each task, if the score is below 5 a list of corrective actions will appear for that task, each corrective action will have a checkbox, so the station can choose to implement it...

I've coded in raw html how the form would look like:

[image: How the form looks like]

My problem is I don't know how to migrate this to Symfony type forms.

I don't know how to load a list of unmapped fields (groups, tasks and corrective actions) and then create a relationship with mapped fields (each task selected score and each task selecteds corrective actions)

Obviously I'm not asking for code I can copy and paste, I need ideas of how to implement this or some documentation that can help me with this.

I'm working with Symfony 3.1.0 and the next entities:

Checklist->ChecklistGroup->ChecklistGroupTask->ChecklistGroupTaskCorrective
    v                           v                            v
StationChecklist -> StationChecklistTask -> StationCheckListTaskCorrectives

Didn't create StationChecklistGroup as I'm not going to add any kind of field to groups, or maybe should I add it anyway?

**EDIT**
In case it helps here is my db structure, maybe I could implement it better (some fields are missing). It's spanish, but I think you can understand it, punto_venta is my station entity:
[image: DB Mapping]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague on some points so I'll try to help you as much as I can:

- To handle collections of form elements (like your Groups of your Tasks), you should use `CollectionType`.
- Having unmapped forms transforming data into real entities is an underwhelming use of the Form component, so try to have FormTypes with data_classes.
- IMO you should have one FormType for each of your entities which maps it. So when a User creates a Checklist, render a ChecklistFormType, which is going to have a `groups` field (`CollectionType` of `GroupFormTypes`). Then create `GroupFormType` with a `tasks` field (`CollectionType` of `CorrectiveActionsFormType`) etc.
- After that, the challenge will be to make your code reusable for `Stations` but I question a bit your model here: are `StationChecklists` really different than `Checklists`? And `StationChecklistTasks` than `ChecklistGroupTasks`? Maybe you could use interfaces or superclasses to map better these similar entities, and then have FormType mapping these interfaces/superclasses, instead of the actual child entities.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck in that challenge. I can already create checklists, and I did it as you suggested with a FormType for each entity. My StationChecklist entity is basically a table joined with entity Checklist and entity Station, adding some fields like "DateLimit" and "ImplementationDate". 

Then StationChecklistTasks will contain the score of each task, and it's joined with StationChecklist and ChecklistTask... 

And finally StationChecklistTaskCorrective only add a boolean field to know what corrective actions had been executed.

Comment: How does it work when the user creates a StationChecklist? Is the form the same than for Checklist, but with a Station to select at first?

Comment: First the user select in which station wants to operate and what checklist wants to implement, then I send both the selected checklist id and selected station id to a new controller, there I can load the entities by the retrieved ids.

Comment: So what's your real problem right now? If your checklist creation process is fine and you can link a checklist to a station, everything works as expected, right?

Comment: My problem comes with form generation. I'm trying to create the "FormTypes" properly the symfony way. For example what field type should I use to generate 4 radio buttons for each ChecklistTask that will store the selected one in StationChecklistTask. And the same happen with corrective actions, what field should I use to add a checkbox to each corrective action and then store it in StationChecklistTaskCorrective.

Comment: For radio buttons use ChoiceType. For checkbox, use CheckboxType.